# AS3 Checking an Array to see if a value exists

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, indexof

I have an array:

```
public var myMap: Array = [ //Set tile locations
                        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
                        [1, 0, 0, 0, 13, 2, 9, 10, 6, 1],
                        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 1],
                        [1, 0, 2, 4, 2, 0, 3, 0, 7, 1],
                        [1, 3, 2, 2, 0, 3, 2, 0, 0, 1],
                        [1, 0, 3, 5, 13, 0, 8, 2, 0, 1],
                        [1, 11, 2, 3, 2, 0, 2, 12, 0, 1],
                        [1, 0, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 0, 2, 1],
                        [1, 3, 0, 3, 0, 11, 2, 0, 10, 1],
                        [1, 2, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 1],
                        [1, 3, 2, 0, 3, 0, 0, 2, 10, 1],
                        [1, 12, 0, 0, 13, 2, 3, 0, 0, 1],
                        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
                    ];
```

And I want to check if a value exists and if it does not exist, i want to do something.

What I have is this function that I tried based on previous questions:

```
public function levelTwo() {
    if(myMap.indexOf(10)==-1) {
        trace('win')
    }
}
```

I can't seem to get it working though. It is tracing 'win' as soon as i run the game.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16647556/counting-number-of-occurances-in-an-array/16647696#16647696 O(N) solution, using indexOf is a O(N^2) solution which is much more slower

Comment: @fsbmain I think you misunderstood his problem.

Comment: Yes, the link I posted does not exactly answers the question, I just wanted to highlite that _indexOf_ is not that innocent, it adds additional level of algorithm complexity. So if method used intensively it's better to consider to caching of data to maps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `myMap` is a 2D array (an array of arrays), you'll have to check each array in `myMap` instead of just checking `myMap`:

**Edit based on comment**: if you want to continually check the array, you'll want to add an `ENTER_FRAME` listener to `stage`, this will cause `levelTwo` to be called "on tick."

```
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, levelTwo);    

public function levelTwo($event:Event) { // need to accept an event argument
    var found:Boolean = false;
    for each(var arr:Array in myMap)
    {
        if(arr.indexOf(10)!= -1) {
            found = true;
        }
    }

    if(!found)
    {
        trace("win");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks you I was able to get your code to work sort of. I totally did not explain my problem clearly but is there a way to get your code to check constantly for '10'. Right now it only runs when i start my game but i want it to check constantly, i tried using a while loop with little success. currently i just put the function into every movement key to check after my character moves, but would prefer a more efficient way. If not, your code still worked and thank you again :)

Comment: because the values in each array of myMap are changing constantly, i need a way to check constantly,, not just once - if they makes my situation more clear

Comment: I've adjusted the answer to meet your needs.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, on your current code: `indexOf(10) == -1` is saying that `10` does *not* occur in the array, because `indexOf` returns `-1` if there is no occurrence of the value. What you mean is `indexOf(10) != -1` which is to say that `10` *does* occur at some index in the array. However, `indexOf` does **NOT** search inner arrays, only the immediate values of the array, and since your `myMap` array only contains more arrays, not numbers directly, `indexOf` will always find no occurrence of the number and return `-1`; this is why you always get `win` immediately. You need to search the inner arrays.

Marcela already posted one approach, using 2 loops.

You could also do this, which is a little more terse:

```
if(array2d.some(function(array:Array, ...args):Boolean {
    return array.indexOf(10) != -1;
})){
    // found '10'
}
```

The callback could be written as a re-usable closure, like this:

```
function arrayHasValue(value:*):Function {
    return function(a:Array, i:int, a2d:Array):Boolean {
        return a.indexOf(value) != -1;
    }
}
// usage:
if(arr.some(arrayHasValue(8))){
    // found '8'
}
if(arr.some(arrayHasValue(3))){
    // found '3'
}
```

Of course, you should probably just encapsulate whatever solution you use in a function, for example:

```
function myMapContains(value:int):Boolean {
    for(var i:int = 0; i < myMap.length; i++){
        for(var ii:int = 0; ii < myMap[i].length; ii++){
            if(myMap[i][ii] === value)
                return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
// usage
if(myMapContains(10)){
    // found '10'
}
```

Worth mentioning, though, since your map is a grid, you don't need a 2d array. You can use a flat array and instead of looking up elements by `map[row][column]` you lookup by `map[row * numColumns + column]`. Using a flat array would then make finding a value easy: `map.indexOf(value)`.